# PrimeFaces 3.4 RC1, dialog not recognizing the Managed Bean property

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish-3

I have included the `primefaces-3.4RC1.jar` in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory. In my controller im autowiring my model bean like

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyController{

@Autowired
Location loc;

//other stuff

}
```

my `Location` class looks like

```
public class Location{     
    private Integer countryId;
    //getters setters
}
```

my view looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <div class="contentBox cornerBorder border">

    <p:dialog>
    <table class="DialogTable">                                                     
    <tr>
     <td><label>Country</label></td> 
        <h:selectOneMenu required="true" id="contry" styleClass="text-box" value="#{myController.loc.countryId}">   
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^here it gives warning and if i run it crashes 

    </tr>
    </table>
    </p:dialog>
```

when i click on a link to open the dialog it throws an error that the property `countryId` could not be found. If i remove the `value="myController.loc.countryId"` it run ok...
anybody to guide me in the right direction

P.S: i have made the appropriate entries in the application context.xml

---

the actual error

> SEVERE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:
>   /WebPages/personal/personalDiv.xhtml @230,119
>   value="#{myController.loc.countryId}": The class
>   'com.deltasoft.controller.myController' does not have the property
>   'loc'.

Comment: I think you would need to annotated MyController with @ManagedBean and some scope, then you would need a getter for loc

Comment: @AkselWillgert i have edited the question to add more details i have already annotating the controller with managed bean and defined the scope

Comment: But you do have the getter? also a typo i think: countryID vs countryId ?

Comment: i have removed the typo and do i need the getter and setter even if i have Autowired the member ? by the way i just tried removing the `@Autowired` annotation from the `loc` and defined its getter and setter, no luck

Comment: In the above post you shouldn't annotate `Location loc` with `@Autowired`.You should annotate with `@ManagedProperty`.Change it and it should work fine.

Comment: 3.4 RC1 is an old beta version. Why are you using an old beta version? If it were just 3.4 or 3.3, okay, but a beta version?

Comment: @BalusC yup from the back of my mind same sort of voices were coming that y im using the RC, i changed it to 3.4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to change your code like this.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MyController{

@ManagedProperty
private Location loc;   // Getters and Setters.

//other stuff

}
```

and

```
@component
public class Location{     
    private Integer countryId;
    //getters setters
}
```

and in your spring.xml you should do

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan="path to Location class path"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: do i need to define the getters and setters of the managed prop?

Comment: Yes. It's just like `@Autowired` but `Autowired ` is to inject spring beans into another spring defined bean. And `ManagedProperty` is to inject Spring or JSF created bean into a  JSF `@ManagedBean`.